# Deleting a table row through query

Tags: mysql

At this moment i am trying to modify this plugin that deletes table rows to delete ONLY rows that don't contain the word "Cekanje" in the column "Status", this is the code and the solution i am trying to build, if anyone can help me:

```
$tableId = (int)$_POST['table_id'];
$idKey = sanitize_text_field($_POST['id_key']);
$idVal = (int)$_POST['id_val'];

$wpdb->delete($mySqlTableName, array($idKey => $idVal));
$columnsMeta = WDTConfigController::loadColumnsFromDB($tableId, array($idColName));

if (count($columnsMeta) == 0) {
    $returnResult['error'] = __('Supplied id column not exist.', 'wpdatatables');
    echo json_encode($returnResult);
    exit();
} else {
    $columnMeta = $columnsMeta[0];

    if ($columnMeta->id_column) {
        $idColumnKey = sanitize_text_field($columnMeta->orig_header);

        $deleteRowIds = $rows[$idColumnKey];

        foreach ($deleteRowIds as $rowId) {
            $rowId = (int)$rowId;

            if (empty($rowId)) {
                continue;
            }

            do_action('wpdatatables_excel_before_delete_row', $rowId, $tableId);

            $res = $wpdb->delete($mySqlTableName, array($idColumnKey => $rowId));
```

And this is the solution I am trying to do to prevent the deletion of rows with "Status" = "Cekanje"

```
$dontdelete = $wpdb -> get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM SaveContactForm7_1 WHERE id != $idKey"));

if($dontdelete)
{
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually wpdb delete function works with an array of data, so i just put two variables in and solved it.

```
    $wpdb->delete($mySqlTableName, array($idKey => $idVal, Status => "Cekanje"));
```

And solved.